# What Jacobians does MATLAB's bvp4c evaluate?

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I am trying to debug my "singular Jacobian" issues with MATLAB'S bvp4c. The question that I have is: which Jacobians are being evaluated? We have the nonlinear system of ODE's y' = f(x, y). I assume that the derivatives of f_i with respect to y_j are put into a matrix and evaluated at some values of y. Maybe this matrix should be invertible for the bvp4c algorithm, although I have found the algorithm to converge when this is not the case.

What about the residuals for the boundary conditions g(ya,yb) = 0? I assume the derivatives of g_i with respect to ya_j are taken. This gives a matrix. Also, the derivative of g_i with respect to yb_j can taken. This also gives a matrix. Does bvp4c evaluate these Jacobians? If so, then they would always be singular if any of the g_i's don't contain a ya or a yb.
Can someone point me to some theory that will illuminate the singular Jacobian error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to all of that. The solver puts all the step equations and the boundary conditions into a large non-linear system and applies some Newton or Newton-like method to it. In a very simplified version, you could use trapezoidal steps in the middle, so that your system is

```
left_bc(x[0],y[0])=0
y[1]-y[0] - 0.5*( x[1]-x[0]) * ( f(x[0],y[0]) + f(x[1],y[1]) ) = 0
...
y[N]-y[N-1] - 0.5*( x[N]-x[N-1]) * ( f(x[N-1],y[N-1]) + f(x[N],y[N]) ) = 0
right_bc(x[N],y[N])=0
```

As you can see, the Jacobians of `f` wrt. `y` are blocks in the Jacobian of that system. As with any large non-linear system, the solution process depends critically on the initial point.

BVP4c uses a 4th order collocation method instead of the 2nd order trapezoidal steps (which is also in the class of collocation methods).